# Export filtered list to Excel in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, filter, excel, export

I have a question about Excel export. I saw a bunch of negative answers on that, but not recent ones.
In SharePoint 2013, is there still no out of the box solution to export a filtered list in Excel ? 
I know that it's possible to create views to do so, but it's really not possible here, as we would have to create a lot of views, and maintain them ...
I'm new to 2013, and I thought maybe there could be something to do using search or new kinds of webparts

Thank you